# Slow Highcharts performance with thousands of series

Tags: performance, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in my project and sometimes I need to display 2000+ series on the chart.

The time of adding series and redrawing a chart is really high. Is there any way to make it to display faster?

What I have already done:

1. Series added without redrawing, then I call chart.redraw()
2. Disabled animation
3. Disabled dataGrouping

Here are the results (adding 2000 and 4000 series to an empty chart):

1. Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m:

   Total series count: 2000
   Series added: 5775ms
   Chart redrawed: 11351ms

   Total series count: 4000
   Series added: 36497ms
   Chart redrawed: 51985ms
2. Firefox 40.0.2

   Total series count: 2000
   Series added: 1769ms
   Chart redrawed: 7405ms

   Total series count: 4000
   Series added: 6153ms
   Chart redrawed: 23464ms
3. IE 11
   Total series count: 2000
   Series added: 14547ms
   Chart redrawed: 50153ms

   Total series count: 4000
   Series added: 66558ms
   Chart redrawed: 229382ms (229 seconds!!)

Could you please tell me, is there any way to increase the speed?
Thank you.

Here is the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1b5ghyf/)

```
$(function () {     

var addManySeries = function(count)
{
    var seriesToAdd = count;
    var d = [];
    var temp = [];              

    for (var i = 0; i < seriesToAdd; i++) {
        temp = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            temp.push(Math.random() * 1000);
        }

        d.push({data: temp, name: 'Series ' + i.toString()});
    }                                 

    $('#log').append("<br/>Total series count: " + (chart.series.length + d.length).toString());
    var s = Date.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < seriesToAdd; i++) {            
        chart.addSeries(d[i], false);
    }
    $('#log').append("<br/>Series added: " + (Date.now() -s).toString() + "ms");                                  
    chart.redraw(); 
    console.log((Date.now() - s).toString());
    $('#log').append("<br/>Chart redrawed: " + (Date.now() - s).toString()+ "ms");
};

var chart_options = {
    chart:{
        type:'line',
        renderTo: 'container',
        animation: false
    },        
    plotOptions: {
            line: {
                animation: false,
                shadow: false,
                marker:{
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
    tooltip:{
        animation : false
    },
    legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    series: {
        dataGrouping: false
    }
};

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_options);

var chart_options = {
    chart:{
        type:'line',
        renderTo: 'container',
        animation: false
    },        
    plotOptions: {
            line: {
                animation: false,
                shadow: false,
                marker:{
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
    tooltip:{
        animation : false
    },
    legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    series: {
        dataGrouping: false
    }
};

chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart_options);

$('#add2000Series').click(function() {                      
    addManySeries(2000);
});
$('#add4000Series').click(function() {                      
    addManySeries(4000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) 2000 series x 10 points is 20000 elements in SVG, try to test pushing native element and measure

2) dataGrouping is available only in Highstock and should be defined in plotOptions not series

3) Why you use a addSeries multiple time, instead of prepare a array of series objects in native javascript?

4) You can use a [boost](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost) module

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to play with native elements and boost module and add testing results. To your 3rd question - I didn't find any difference in time between addSeries function and configuring a set of series while creating a chart. I'll also add some test results.